# Options for monthly payments and annual payments on same contribution page

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

I am using civicrm 4.6.1 on Drupal 7.3.5.

I need a contribution page that lets users choose between annual memberships and monthly "sustaining" membership payments. I have set up price sets and membership types for each, but I can't seem to get both price sets on the same contribution page.

If there is not a way to do that, do I set up a contribution page for each and send my members through a screening page?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could make a single priceset which is capable of accepting the various combinations that are possible, then implement a design which provides a different UI for selecting the preferred amounts.

An example CiviCRM membership/donate page which implements a similar approach is the one at http://greens.org.nz/join - the visible elements trigger changes in (hidden) CiviCRM form elements to deliver the required user experience.

CiviCRM permits you to ensure a minimum amount on the contribute form, but that won't account for the combination of payment term and amount. With a small extension you can implement any validation required to ensure the correct amounts are paid (so a user can't submit the form with a cheap annual membership).